# How to code the string data in a column so that I could apply machine learning techniques for classification, for example k-means?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, machine-learning, hash

I have string variables (Range[VarName]) in a column with respective ID (Range[kksId]). I need to create an algorithm that will classify new variables to existing ID or if it is not possible put them separately in N/A class.

[image]

How to code the string data in a column so that I could apply machine learning techniques for classification, for example k-means?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, since your variable "Range[kksId]" is your target class, you map each of theese strings to a unique integer number, here's an example of how that could be achieved in python:

```
import pandas as pd


def _categoricalToNumeric(dataset):
    categoric_id_mapping = {}
    curr_id_to_assign = 0
    for row in dataset.index:
        categorical_value = dataset.loc[row]
        if categorical_value in categoric_id_mapping:
            dataset.loc[row] = categoric_id_mapping[categorical_value]
        else:
            categoric_id_mapping[categorical_value] = curr_id_to_assign
            dataset.loc[row] = curr_id_to_assign
            curr_id_to_assign += 1
    return dataset


df = pd.read_excel('DataModel.xlsx', index_col=0)
df['Range[kksId]'] = _categoricalToNumeric(df['Range[kksId]'])
```

Then, as for the string feature, in a simple classifier, they are generally mapped each caracter into a variable. Example:

```
R_r_DegPit1_In_St
R_r_DegPit1_In
```

becomes:

```
x0  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16
 R   _   r   _   D   e   g   P   i   t   1   _   I   n   _   S   t
 R   _   r   _   D   e   g   P   i   t   1   _   I   n  \0  \0  \0
```

Since you will have as many variables as the longest string in your dataset, for the strings which will not occupy all variables you should fill the remaining variables with a value indicating the empty character. You should also change the character values to numeric, however, it is important not to reset the numeric counting based on each column. The result could be something like this:

```
x0  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7  x8  x9 x10 x11 x12  x13 x14 x15 x16
 3   1   4   1   5  10  11   6  12  13   2   1   7   14   1   8   9
 3   1   4   1   5  10  11   6  12  13   2   1   7   14   0   0   0
```

Keep in mind that more advanced ML/DL techniques handles their strings in different ways.